# How do I set the file mask for find in path only for js or jsx in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

I want to use Find in Path only for js and jsx files in WebStorm. I tried to set `\*.js\*` in file mask but it includes other files like `js.map.`

I really appreciate any advise how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify several file types using commas as separators, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.3/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html#exclude_type

[image]